# Disconnect vertical tab connector from PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, repair, replacement

I'm trying to replace a PCB, but I can't figure out how to unplug these connectors. They seem to be a "quick connect" style. I've tried tugging on them and wiggling them, but they won't come off. There's a little bump that fits into the hole on the vertical tab that's holding them in. I've also tried to get a small screwdriver under the strip of metal that the bump is on, but there isn't really room to get it under. How can I unplug these connections without breaking them? Breaking the PCB is probably okay, since it's apparently already broken (and that's why I'm replacing it).

[image]
[image]

Here is the replacement PCB: [link](https://wenproducts.com/products/34018-0805asm-motor-driver-pcb-and-potentiometer-assembly-for-wen-34018?_pos=1&_sid=82b4a5dc8&_ss=r).

Comment: Just pull. These take a lot of force to remove, but all you have to do is pull.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are commonly called Faston(tm), quick-connect, or tab connectors.

They often require significant force to remove (unless you want them to stay connected, in which case they will fall off).

If a staight pull will not disconnect them, and you are able to get something under the end of the female connector, you may be able to pry the female connector up a bit to make removal easier.

Comment: "unless you want them to stay connected, in which case they will fall off" This is the solution  However, another outcome from wanting them to remain connected is that the wire slips out of the crimped end.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a quick-connect removal tool, or make one:

[https://www.amazon.com/Lisle-13120-Electrical-Connector-Separator/dp/B0002STTPW/ref=sr_1_32?crid=WEWZ55SRZ1AE&keywords=quick+connect+terminal+removal+tool&qid=1670712823&sprefix=quick+connect+terminal+removal+tool%2Caps%2C102&sr=8-32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002STTPW)

[image]

I have also had some success using needle nose pliers to go between the male and female connectors to loosen them for removal.

Comment: Why is this better than getting leverage with a screwdriver?

Comment: The hooked end works where there are components in the way. One could also make a similar tool. I wonder why the downvote?

Comment: Because in this specific case, with a single board which is even allowed to be destroyed, getting an extra tool does not at all seem applicable to me, and the tool seemed completely useless for incidental use. The explanation of "when components are in the way" does make this valid, but I can't remove my down vote any more unless the answer is edited apparently. TIL votes get locked...